# How do I make my posts only peer-edit reviewed?

Tags: support, editing

I prefer to only allow people to edit my questions after I confirm the edit. How can I do this?

Comment: why has this been downvoted at all? seems a fair question, if impossible to do.

Comment: @bharal:  Becasue that's not how the StackExchange sites work.

Comment: @John Dibling yeah, it's because meta is different in what constitutes a downvote. My mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.

Editing other peoples posts is a [privilege earned at 2000 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit). It's a major part of the site because this site (and all other stackexchange sites) is about getting the best answer to any question anywhere on the internet. To this end, if you've earned enough reputation, then you're trusted enough that any edits you put out are for the good of the question/answer.

Anyone with less than 2000 rep can still submit an edit, it will have to be approved by other people on the [review edits page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits).

Comment: Oh, so anyone with over 2000 rep can edit my posts without my review then?

Comment: @gameaddict Yes, you will however get a notification (I can't remember where exactly) and if you don't agree with it, you can always roll back the edit to one you're more satisfied with. If however your rollback is deemed unnecessary, it may be rolled back again.

Comment: @gameaddict Also people with less than 2000 rep can edit posts - but they must be approved by higher rep users before the go live on the site. See "[Other people can edit my posts?!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#editing)" from the FAQ.

Comment: can't wait . . . .